# Как сделать всплывающее окно с текстом в QtDesigner

Tags: python, qt-designer, pyside

и так, при нажатии на кнопку с названием `accountinf` будет выводится всплывающее окно с Label текстом + ниже будут кнопки `отмена` и `ок`

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: @Духсообщества какбы она не проблема а вопрос

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pyqt/pyqt_qmessagebox.htm

Comment: Кзлч Вв пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve] , который вы уже успели написать.

Comment: https://pythonprogramminglanguage.com/pyqt5-message-box/